# Get the sum of a column based on another table's data

Tags: mysql

So basically, i have 2 tables and i need to get the sum of one column. But the rows i need to select have criteria in another table. i've come up with this query, but it always returns null.

```
SELECT sum( secondary_lpt.loan_amount )
FROM secondary_lpt
LEFT JOIN loan_log ON loan_log.loan_guid = secondary_lpt.loan_guid
WHERE (
    secondary_lpt.lock_Date
    BETWEEN date( '2013-02-19 15:25:55' )
    AND date( '2013-04-19 15:25:55' )
)
AND (
    loan_log.loan_ms_funding = NULL
    OR loan_log.loan_ms_funding = ''
)
AND (
    loan_log.loan_transdetail = 'Active Loan'
)
```

I'm having a hard time wording what I'm trying to say, so i guess that could be part of the problem.

Comment: Have you verified that your `join` and `where` clause are actually returning you rows that you want?  Replace the `sum()` with a `*` and add a limit to inspect that you do have rows coming back.   What is the datatype of `secondary_lpt.loan_amount`?

Comment: Change this `loan_log.loan_ms_funding = NULL` to `loan_log.loan_ms_funding IS NULL`, and your last condition `loan_log.loan_transdetail = 'Active Loan'` will change this join to inner join

Comment: @scwagner i can get the sum if i don't have the WHERE clause in there. its an int type, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fields of table in the left join clause are used in the where clause, it works as inner join usually(it expects the column to have a value). So move ur where clause to ON clause